# Any good Exchange clients to replace Outlook?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, exchange

Is there a lightweight desktop application to connect to an Exchange server to just get mail?  Ideally, the app would be free.

I am looking to replace Outlook for something that loads quicker and takes up less memory, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use just about any mail clients to connect to Exchange and utilize POP3 or IMAP, but I don't know if you would get the full array of Exchange features.

Comment: Exchange only has IMAP and it has to be turned on.

Comment: @Daniel Since When? I have used Exchange for years both for POP3 and IMAP? We are even using it at work in testing on the Exchange 2010 Beta's?

Comment: @Daniel By default exchange only does its native MAPI, but it will certainly do both POP3 and IMAP, but you admin has to configure it.

Answer (score 5):

Exchange provides IMAP access to a nice client, [Mozilla Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/features/).
It even has a calendar plugin, [lightning](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/2313) (not directly usable with exchange).

Comment: I've tried Thunderbird before, but our company mailserver seems to use some evil Microsoft-specific protocol for doing something that Thunderbird can't seem to handle.

Comment: You can enable IMAP and SMTP on exchange - convincing the administration is a social task.

Comment: @Jason S: Evolution can do appointment/calendar handling with exchange, even over a standard IMAP connection, if that's what you're after.  There's a separate Exchange connection method which takes an OWA URL; I haven't managed to get that working yet though.

The Microsoft-specific protocol you're talking about is MAPI, as far as I know.  Evolution has a separate, newer MAPI plugin for exchange, too.  That crashed badly for me, but it's still experimental, so give it some time.

Answer (score 3):

You can connect to Exchange using POP and IMAP, so therefore you can use any mail client. I use Apple Mail on my Mac personally and still use Outlook on Windows, but I also use Thunderbird on occasion.

If you want something completely free and have access to Exchange from the outside you can also use Outlook Web Access.

Comment: POP and IMAP have to be enabled by your system administrator, and I've worked at more than 1 company where they are both disabled. Outlook uses something different to connect, and sometimes that is the only thing allowed. :(

Comment: @Jon Agreed. However it can be done and with good motivation some administrators will allow it.

Answer (score 2):

[Evolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_%28software%29) (for GNOME) works very well with Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

You could go for Gmail and POP into your Exchange server. ;)

Comment: Now that would be excellent! I can't stand Outlook!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the memory usage of this, but [Zimbra Desktop](http://www.zimbra.com/products/desktop.html)

If your Exchange server has OWA/Webmail access,  you can use the [OWA plugin](http://groups.google.com/group/thunderbird-webmail-extension).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the web access on the Exchange server.

Comment: OWA, in Exchange 2003 at least, is pretty horrible for anyone who really needs to manage their email folders, read state, search old emails, etc.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I used to work for a company that used OWA 2003 *exclusively*. Everyone. Not kidding.

Answer (score 1):

This looks promising: http://www.emclient.com/, according to the website, it has calendar and contacts support.

Answer (score 0):

There is a port of [Evolution for Windows](http://www.dipconsultants.com/evolution/).

Comment: Ugh - have you actually used it - very buggy.

Comment: No. That explains why it has not been updated.